# Incompatibility between import and minted?

Tags: minted, input, import

`minted` doesn't seem to work with `import` using `\subimport*`. Is there a way to fix that because I'm becoming addicted to the package `import`?

Main file

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{python}
for i in range(4):
    print(i**2)
\end{minted}

\input{content/intro}

\subimport*{content/}{intro}   % <-- PB here.

\end{document}
```

File `content/intro.tex`

```
\begin{minted}{python}
for i in range(4):
    print(i**2)
\end{minted}
```

Comment: Reported as an issue on the source site here:
https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/251

Comment: Good job. I will wait for a fixing.